# Is that normal that Eclipse forgets my 12 recent files at relaunch?

Tags: eclipse, launch

Hullo,

I have Eclipse :

Version: Juno Service Release 1

Build id: 20120920-0800

Is that normal that quitting and relaunching Eclipse make him forget the list of my recent files in the File menu ? This is quite annoying.

If someone has a solution against that, I would like it !

Thank you,

Nicolas

Comment: This used to work, as recently as Indigo version I believe.  I also seek an answer for why it does not maintain a persisted recent files list any more.

Comment: I don't know what Indigo is. Are you trying to say that you encounter this bug too ? Can some Eclipse person take a look and fix that ?

Comment: Indigo is an Eclipse release code name.  Juno follows Indigo and is the current release.  I'm saying that until recently the recent files list was persisted between sessions, so I think this might be a bug introduced in Juno.